# How can I force Thunderbird to reload an IMAP folder structure from Outlook.com

Tags: thunderbird, imap, outlook.com

Thunderbird is freshly installed and with an Outlook.com email account using an IMAP connection. New messages can be written, sent and received, all new messages arrive both in Thunderbird client and can be seen in Outlook.com online through a browser.

However, there are also messages from a past service which were uploaded to the Outlook.com account; these messages are held in structured folders. These folders are wanted going forwards as new messages will be kept in them. All folders and messages are available via Outlook.com online. Within Thunderbird, the parent folder of the folder structure shows, and shows the first child folder created within it; however none of the other child folders are visible to Thunderbird - they are not visible in the message store list (left-hand column) and they are not visible on the Subscribe folders list.

[Image showing folders in Outlook and sync folders in Thunderbird out-of-sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssnU.png)

The goal is to have all messages and all folders available in Thunderbird at all times and sync'ed with Outlook.com

*How can I force Thunderbird to refresh the Subscribe folders list, and ultimately collect, display, and manage my messages?*

**Actions tried**:
Similar issues appear to have been around for several years, so these are the actions I've tried (and have failed):

Rollup and unroll folder list.

Close anti-virus, restart Thunderbird and refresh folders.

Subscribe folder list:
Untick child and parent folders, retick, resubscribe.
Use Refresh button - *nothing appears to happen, no screen messages*.

"Items for Offline Use" list Child and parent folders, untick and re-tick.

Folder Properties >> Synchronisation >> Select this folder for offline use - *ticked*
Folder Properties >> General Information >> Include messages in this folder in Global Search results - *ticked*
Folder Properties >> General Information >> When getting new messages for this account always check this folder - *ticked*
Folder Properties >> General Information >> Repair Folder button - *nothing appears to happen, no screen messages*.

Tools » Account Settings » Server Settings » Advanced » Show only subscribed folders ... uncheck this option -  *checked and unchecked makes no difference*

Tools -> Settings -> General -> Config Editor
mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new - set to TRUE
mail.imap.auto_unsubscribe_from_noselect_folders - false ... *could not find this setting*
mail.server.default.using_subscription - false - false ... *could not find this setting*

**Operating environment**

Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) v22H2

Thunderbird 102.12.0 (64 bit) - *new installation, Thunderbird has not been installed on this PC before*

Outlook.com - *new (free) account created June 2023 (account created prior to installing Thunderbird)*

Comment: Can't you upload these messages to TB, same as you did for the Outlook.com account?

Comment: check out this thread (not only the "chosen solution") https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1363677  There's somewhere a checkbox " 'Server supports folders that contain subfolders and messages' ". Also check out the rest of the thread. hope it helps

Comment: @harrymc 
A) Thunderbird sync's with Outlook.com via IMAP - if I were to load the folders and messages to TB, at some point I am then likely to double up every message within Outlook.com - this is then likely to create another (larger) clean-up exercise?
B) Thunderbird has no direct import for the old message format (I was able to export the original message store as a PST, but this then had to be uploaded to Outlook.com via a friend's PC with the Outlook program installed).  I would have preferred to import the PST directly to TB and sort the folders from there, but it wasn't an option.

Comment: @1NN
Yes, there are two options in Advanced Account Settings. "Show only subscribed folders" (unselected) and "Server supports folders that contain sub-folders and messages" (selected).  
Thanks for the link, yes I have been through these options.  
None of these has yet been successful.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you used another application to access Outlook.com, *and still have the app installed, with its local files*, such as Outlook applications' .pst,  you can import those messages to Thunderbird. Hopefully, this would also set up the folder structure in Thunderbird so that messages in subfolders are downloaded.

   A. In Thunderbird, go to *Tools -> Import...*

   [image: Import to Thunderbird]

   B. Select the application, e.g., Outlook.

   C. Press <kbd>Continue</kbd> and finish.
2. If you *do not have the application installed*,

   A. Temporarily reinstall it.

   B. download all messages to that application.

   C. Proceed as above in 1.

   D. After checking that Thunderbird subfolders are populated, remove the application and delete its local files.

Comment: What about if you don't have such an application? Needing to download and install Outlook, to create a PST as a "work around" doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add to Outlook a Gmail account and through it port
the data to the MBOX format of Thunderbird.

**Configure Gmail in Outlook**

- Login to Gmail, click the Settings button and position to
  "Forwarding and POP/IMAP", then select "Enable IMAP"
- In Outlook, go to menu *File > Add Account* and provide the
  Gmail credentials and click Next
- Use Outlook’s import/export wizard to add the PST file to the
  Gmail account.

**Use Google Takeout to save the PST as an MBOX file**

- Start Chrome and position to the URL
  https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin?service=backup
- In the screen for "Select data to include",
  click on "Download your data" and check the "Mail" option
- For "Delivery Method", select "Export once"
- For "File type & size", the file format of MBOX and the maximum
  file size (2 GB)
- Click "Create Export" to save the MBOX file.

**Import the MBOX files to Thunderbird**

- Open Thunderbird
- Install the addon
  [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/)
- In menu *Tools > ImportExportTools NG*, select
  "Import MBOX file" to import the generated MBOX file.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Import PST to Mozilla Thunderbird Step by Step](https://www.shoviv.com/blog/how-to-import-pst-thunderbird-step-by-step/).